# Repeating task on page every x seconds and report back to UI thread (e.g. set TextBlock.Text or ViewModel property)

Tags: c#, mvvm, windows-runtime, task-parallel-library, windows-store-apps

I've got a Windows 8 App and want to query a resource every 15 seconds for a status change (get onto a webservice url), the result should be written into a ViewModel property, which is bound to the UI (XAML).

If we leave the page, the task should be terminated.

I've taken a look at background tasks, but they seem to be an overkill for this page specific task.

Also played around with Task.Run() and the Dispatcher but I couldn't get it to work with a while loop.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to run some action every x seconds, then you should use a timer. Since you want to run it on the WinRT UI thread, the correct one is [`Windows.UI.Xaml.DispatcherTimer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br244250.aspx).

When you leave the page, you should `Stop()` the timer, so that its `Tick` event stops being raised.

If you want to `await` something in the event handler, you need to make it `async`, e.g.:

```
timer.Tick += async (s, e) =>
{
    var client = new HttpClient();
    var response = await client.GetAsync(…);
    …
}
```

This will create an `async void` method. Be aware that [you should almost never do that](http://www.tonicodes.net/blog/why-you-should-almost-never-write-void-asynchronous-methods/), except when you're writing an event handler.

Comment: If you're performing some long action in the event handler, then of course it will block the UI thread, that's what you asked for.

Comment: Can you give it async to me? ;-)             _timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1); _timer.Tick += (s, e) => { Dispatcher.RunAsync(new CoreDispatcherPriority(), () => { Foo.Text = DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString(); }); }; - That's not long (right now), isn't it?

Comment: @tkrause You don't need to use `Dispatcher.RunAsync()` if you're using `DispatcherTimer`, you're already on the right thread. But I don't understand why would your code cause any problems.

Comment: You were right. Without the dispatcher it works just fine. Thank you so far! :-) But any idea on how to make this async?

Comment: @tkrause I have no idea what do you mean by that. There is nothing in your example above that could be made async.

Comment: You said it. It is an example. I have web service call in there: var client = new HttpClient(); client.GetAsync("..."); Called via a service provider, but you get the point. I just don't want to block the UI thread.

Comment: @tkrause In that case, you can just make the event handler `async`: `timer.Tick += async (s, e) => { var response = await client.GetAsync(…); };`.

Comment: Didn't know that this is possible. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to work with the **Dispatcher** of the UI thread. You can save it into a static member to get it from everywhere or you can get it diretcly from the active UI on the fly. But after you have the **Dispatcher** you can call (and await) the **RunAsync** method.

```
await Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(
    new CoreDispatcherPriority(), action);
```

As action you can use for example a lambda expression or any other predefinied Action you want. In this action you can manipulate UI bound elements.
I hope it could help you.

Comment: Could you please be more spcific with the "I couldn't get it to work with a while loop" part?

Comment: I want to repeat the action over and over again until I leave the page. If I use it with the DispatcherTimer, I don't need a loop anymore, because I can execute my code with every tick.